# CSS, HTML Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I've been trying to get my page to have the following layout attached below but with no luck. I would like to stack the boxes in the second column. Can anyone point me to the right direction?  Thanks.

[image: Layout]

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3rUG7/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 divs, one for the left and one on the right, then inside the right hand div (which is the same size as the left div) have the 3 divs as seperate divs. Something like this in your HTML:

```
<div id="left>
....some stuff....
</div>
<div id="rightContainer">
    <div id="top">
    ....some stuff....
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
    ....some stuff....
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
    ....some stuff....
    </div>
</div>
```

Your CSS will be:

```
#left {
width: 200px;
float:left;
height:600px;
}
#rightContainer {
width: 200px;
float:left;
height:600px;
}
#top, #middle, #bottom {
height:200px;
width:100%;
float:left;
}
```

Should be about what you need (or there abouts!).

Post your code so far and I am sure we can do more :)

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I'm new to this forum so did not realize I had to post my code. I will be sure to do that next time. Both answers worked.  What I was missing was the overall container that contained the 3 divs.

Answer (score 0):

I have created two js fiddles for you to look at. Both use %'s rather than fixed numbers, the first one has even spacing between the horizontal containers on the right hand side (although then they do not share the same bottom with the left hand side) while the second one makes the bottom container on the right hand side have an absolute position, creating uneven spaces between the horizontal containers:
html:

```
<div id="left">

</div>
<div id="right">
  <div id="row1"></div>
  <div id="row2"></div>
  <div id="row3"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#left {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 596px;
  width: 30%;
}

#right {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 600px;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#row1,
#row2,
#row3 {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#row1,
#row2 {
  height: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#row3 {
  height: 20%;
}
```

[same spacing but different bottoms jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L08a18b1/2/)

html:

```
<div id="left">

</div>
<div id="right">
  <div id="row1"></div>
  <div id="row2"></div>
  <div id="row3"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#left {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 596px;
  width: 30%;
}

#right {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 600px;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#row1,
#row2,
#row3 {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#row1,
#row2 {
  height: 35%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#row3 {
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[same bottom but different spacing jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L08a18b1/1/)

Is that close to what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I'm new to this forum so did not realize I had to post my code. I will be sure to do that next time. Both answers worked.  What I was missing was the overall container that contained the 3 divs.

What is the advantage of using position:absolute; position:relative over using float left?

Comment: `float:left;` affects how an element is displayed in relation to other elements within one container. `position:absolute;` really just makes that element's position not affected by other elements. Often both can be used to achieve one purpose. Look at your situation and decide which to use. Eg. if you want something to align left and have other elements wrap around it (eg. a picture with text wrapping around it), `float:left;` makes sense. However, if you want something to appear as though it is on top of other content (eg. text on top of an image), `position:absolute;` is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the explantion!